# Why do some people avoid eating some specific foods on specific days?

Tags: food, non-vegetarian

Lately, I had a conversation with one of my internet friends from India. I asked her about her dietary habits. She told me that in her family they don't eat non-vegetarian food items on Tuesday (Mangalavaara), Thursday (Brihaspativaara), and Saturday (Shanivaara). She also said that they also don't eat Banana on Thursday (Brihaspativaara) because her family worships Brihaspati Deva (a deity in Hinduism or Sanaatana Dharma).

I found it quite peculiar.

Is it compulsory for everyone to follow the same dietary habits? What is the rationale behind following these kinds of dietary habits in Hinduism or Sanaatana Dharma?